# conflict name between class name and subclass name of a module with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, module, namespaces

I have an `Effect` class in models, and a folder `"effect"` like `app/models/effect/` within `Effect::Status` class. Effect class as like module with rails in this configuration.

But I have another class `Status` in models :

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base

  DEATH = 1
```

Now I want call this constant in Effect class, like :

```
class Effect
  def self.apply
    foo = Status::DEATH
  end
end
```

But, I have the following error :

> uninitialized constant Effect::Status::DEATH

I think there is conflict between `Status` and `Effect::Status`

So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First require the `Status` class into `Effect`.

Then, access it using `::` at the front to indicate there is no parent module.

```
require 'status'

class Effect
  def self.apply
    foo = ::Status::DEATH
  end
end
```